# Can we specify parameters for unless function in cached function(in Flask-Cache)

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

From [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) Documentation, cached function takes following parameters - timeout,key_prefix, unless. Unless is descibed as

- > unless – Default None. Cache will always execute the caching
  >   facilities unless this callable is true. This will bypass the caching 
  >   entirely.

Is there a way to pass parameters to unless function, by which we can dynamically know whether to apply the caching or not.

Comment: What values, precisely, are you expecting this callable to accept as arguments? Remember that Flask-Cache will be calling the callable, so you don't really control what the arguments are.

Comment: You can access almost everything inside your function through `request` context. I don't know what you want to do with these unless parameters. Can you give an example?

Comment: Actually accord to some requirements, I wants to disable caching for some particular request(not for the majority ones, but for some). Either I can take arguments as some environment/global variable or as @iurisilvio said by request context also.

Comment: So, you probably don't need these parameters. You have to check these "requirements" in the callable, but they are not passed as parameters, you should access them in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [code as it currently stands](https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache/blob/12afdb0ba452f2e6b6d10a5221cc3713c0d7bd24/flask_cache/__init__.py#L230) this is not possible.  Definitely worth a pull request.